# How do I unprepare the SqlCommand prepared by SqlCommand.Prepare

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sqlclient

Looks like, the only way I can unprepare  is to call `SqlCommand.Dispose()`, even in that case I don't see a unprepare hitting the SQL Server (viewed from SQL Profiler, there is no sp_unprepare). But of course `SqlCommand.Dispose()` does get rid of the `SqlCommand` which in turn get rids of the prepare statement from the server cache.

Is there any other way I can unprepared and still keep the `SqlCommand`.
Best practice says I should unprepare when I don't need it, how can I go about it without calling `SqlCommand.Dispose()`?

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Comment: There is no real need to 'prepare' statements. Just Execute them.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare does not deal with memory like dispose does with objects. Prepare is used to pre-recompile your sql in case you are running the same query over and over, by doing this it may save time. The prepare is executed at the server level, and the plan generated from the statement is fully managed by the database. The concept of unprepared from the client is therefore is not relevant.